# sort_values() with 'key' to sort a column of tuples in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, tuples, key

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Params': {0: (400, 30),
  1: (2000, 10),
  2: (1200, 10),
  3: (2000, 30),
  4: (1600, None)},
 'mean_test_score': {0: -0.6197478578718253,
  1: -0.6164605619489576,
  2: -0.6229674626212879,
  3: -0.7963084775995496,
  4: -0.7854265341671137}})
```

I wish to **sort it according to the first element of the tuples in the first column**.

First column of the desired output:

```
{'Params': {0: (400, 30),
  2: (1200, 10),
  4: (1600, 10),
  1: (2000, 10),
  3: (2000, 30),
```

I have tried to use `df.sort_values(by=('Params'), key=lambda x:x[0])` like I would do with a list and `.sort` but I get the following value error: `ValueError: User-provided` key `function must not change the shape of the array.`

I have looked at the documentation of [`sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) but it did not help much about why lambda does not work.

EDIT: Following @DeepSpace suggestion, I can't do
`df.sort_values(by='Params')` gives `'<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Comment: df.iloc[np.argsort([item[0] for item in df.Params]), :]

Comment: Thanks Eric, I did not know np.argsort(), i am glad to discover it. This article was useful to better understand it.
https://www.datasciencelearner.com/numpy-argsort-use-examples/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The document of [sort_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) says

> `key` should expect a `Series` and return a Series with the same shape as the input.

In `df.sort_values(by=('Params'), key=lambda x:x[0])`, the `x` is actually the `Params` column. By accessing `x` with `x[0]`, you are returning the first element of `x` Series, which is not the same shape as input Series. Thus gives you the error.

If you want to sort by the first element of tuple, you can do

```py
df.sort_values(by='Params', key=lambda col: col.map(lambda x: x[0]))
# or
df.sort_values(by='Params', key=lambda col: col.str[0])
```

Comment: very clear answer, I understand where the problem was now, thanks @Ynjxsjmh !!